# forfiles command ignore a directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line

I want to write a batch that finds all docs less than 50 mb in `c:\` and copy them in a folder **but ignore system directory docs**. I prefer it does not even search in the system dir.

Here is my batch that finds and copies all files less 50 mb in right directory but i can not make it to ignore system from searching or `C:\Windows` directory.

```
@ECHO off
:: variables

SET odrive=%odrive:~0,2%
SET backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y

MKDIR "C:\Users\Documents\USBBackups\DOC\C"

forfiles /P C:\ /M *.DOC* /S /C "cmd /c if @fsize leq 50000000 echo @PATH "  > "C:\Users\Documents\USBBackups\DOCC.txt"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in (C:\Users\Documents\USBBackups\DOCC.txt) do xcopy %%a "C:\Users\Documents\USBBackups\DOC\C" /c /h /i /r /y

@ECHO off
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to tell `forfiles` to exclude certain directories when switch `/S` is provided. You will have to write your own code that does that.

I would not use `forfiles` for that due to poor performance, but standard `for` instead:

```
@echo off
for /D %%D in ("%SystemDrive%\*.*") do (
    if /I not "%%D"=="%SystemRoot%" (
        pushd "%%D"
        for /R %%F in ("*.doc?") do (
            if %%~zF LEQ 50000000 (
                echo %%F
            )
        )
        popd
    )
)
```

Here the root directory level is enumerated by `for /D`. All directories other than `%SystemRoot%` are enumerated recursively by `for /R`.

I changed the search pattern from `*.doc*` to `*.doc?` in order not to include files ending in `.doc.lnk` for example, which I guess you do not want to be retrieved.

Instead of the `echo` command you can directly place your `xcopy` command line with `"%%F"` provided as the copy source.

---

You can do the same directly in command prompt as a one-liner, like this:

```
for /D %D in ("%SystemDrive%\*.*") do @if /I not "%D"=="%SystemRoot%" pushd "%D" & (for /R %F in ("*.doc?") do @if %~zF LEQ 50000000 echo %F) & popd
```

---

I recommend not to walk through the entire directory tree and later filtering by something like `findstr /V /I /L /B /C:"%SystemRoot%"`, because in that case you were wasting time enumerating a huge number of items which you ignore afterwards.

However, if you do want to rely on `forfiles /S`, the working command line looks like this:

```
2> nul forfiles /S /P "C:\\" /M "*.doc*" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE if @fsize LEQ 50000000 echo @path" | findstr /V /I /L /B /C:"\"%SystemRoot%"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. do you have any tip to increase the code  performance and speed

Comment: You're welcome! I can't really improve the performance of the approach using nested `for` loops; however, to make it faster you could perhaps exclude more folders (like `C:\Program Files`); or another idea is not to exclude (a) certain folder(s), but include dedicated folders only, because this might also reduce the overall number of folders...

Comment: thanks for the tip by the way how can i save the result of  your one-line code (for /D ... ) in to a .txt file like the one in my forfiles code. i really tried but it overwrite the notepad in every loop

Comment: Just enclose the entire line in `()`, then put `> "\path\to\textfile.txt" at the beginning or at the end of the line (so the file is written once rather than line by line)...

Comment: sorry to bother when i run it as a batch file get this error "the following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid : %~zF LEQ 50000000 echo %F( & popd) > "C:\Users\Documents\USBBackups\DOCC.txt""

Comment: If you use this line in a batch file, you need to double all `%` signs except those around `SystemRoot` and `SystemDrive`; this is because of `for` -- type `for /?` in a command prompt window and read the help text, it is mentioned therein... but the one-liner is basically the same as my first code snippet...

Comment: I'm trying to do this but I have to get 3 levels lower into my tree structure before I start launching the recursion, so I tried another for loop after the `pushd %%D` so I `pushd %%MyNewVariable` inside but I end up being at the same level I was with `%%D`, I can't manage to find an answer online :/

Comment: I hope you are not literally using `%%MyNewVariable` since a `for` meta-variable has to consist of one letter only. Anyway, for another level, you would need after `pushd "%%~D"`: `for /D %%E in ("%%~D\*") do (`, `pushd "%%~E"`; and before `popd`: `popd`, `)`…

Answer (score 0):

Adapt this technique of using `findstr` to filter out certain names.

To see size of folders in Documents, excluding music, video, or pictures folders.

```
for /f "skip=3 tokens=3" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Personal"') do set doc=%A

for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"^|findstr /l /v "Pictures Music Video"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

However you could start the forfiles command in the `c:\users` or the particular users home folder (`%userprofile%`). You specify to start at `c:\` which includes all folders.

```
forfiles /P %userprofile% /M .DOC /S /C "cmd /c if @fsize leq 50000000 echo @PATH "
forfiles /P c:\users /M .DOC /S /C "cmd /c if @fsize leq 50000000 echo @PATH "
```